# How to remove prospect for a journey (Pardot-ENGAGEMENT STUDIO)?

Tags: salesforce, pardot

I want to create a dynamic list which I going to use as exit criteria,

Let me explain the scenario,

I'm creating a Nurturing Journey using "ENGAGEMENT STUDIO",

To start the Recipient List I'm going to use this dynamic list where I'm straining.

Who I'm targeting?

- New Leads
- Contacts & Accounts

How I'm matching the prospect

To do this I'm maintaining a static list
What is my exit rule?

I wanted to remove prospects when their opportunity stage changed to "Closed Won" or "Closed"

---

I have tried to do this using a dynamic list, please find the attachment below,

[image]

Flow Plan

[image]

Is my approach correct or do I need to chnage my plan?